# Can you make basic mainline dht queries like find_node and ping with the libtorrent library

Tags: java, bittorrent, dht, libtorrent

In my project I want to monitor the bittorrent mainline network. To do so, I must use basic simple queries like find_node, announce_peer etc. What I would like to do is I would first connect to the bootstrap node and then populate my routing table with get_nodes and so on.

Some of the researchers that did similar things before used the libtorrent library, but I can't seem to find how to do it. Does the libtorrent library support this? I am using the java binding library for this(com.frostwire.jlibtorrent).

I was unable to find a lot of examples of usage of this library and I have been reading through the javadoc and can't figure out how to do it.

Is there a better way I should try to do this? I have been stuck for quite some time now, any help is appreciated.

Thanks, M

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might want to try the libtorrent mailing list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#session-handle) only lists some high-level DHT APIs. The lower-level implementation is marked as TORRENT_EXTRA_EXPORT which I believe means it's only meant for testing. The [ping method](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/c5d0ea6332d0044bb4a7c52c572ad3e709114cf3/include/libtorrent/kademlia/node.hpp#L222) specifically is private.

Since you're using java you could use [mldht](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/) (I'm the author), which exposes lower-level functionality too.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Thank you, I'll look into it.

Comment: Hey @the8472. I have 1 or 2 quick questions about the mldht library. I can't seem to reach you anywhere. Could you please email me at malineborovnice@gmail.com, so that I get your contact? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MaticŠincek if it's ok then you can ask questions in github issues, that way other readers can benefit too.